# Partial Differential Equations Question: Find an explicit expression for the solution of the IVP

Tags: partial-differential-equations, characteristics

Find an explicit expression for the solution of the IVP

$$
\begin{cases}
u_{t}(x,t)+u_{x}(x,t)+u(x,t)=e^{t+2x}\\
\\
u(0,x)=0,
\end{cases}
$$

by using the **method of characteristics**

Comment: Hi and welcome to the Math.SE. Questions sounding like "do this for me, please" are poorly received from other members. I you need help, help other users help you for example by explaining what you tried and where did you get stuck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a linear PDE so

$$
u = u^h + u^p
$$

with

$$
u_t^h+u_x^h=-u^h\\
u_t^p+u_x^p+u^p=e^{t+2x}
$$

Using the Characteristics method with $u^h$ we have

$$
\begin{cases}
\frac{dt}{d\tau} = 1 & t(0) = 0 & t(\tau) = \tau\\
\frac{dx}{d\tau} = 1 & x(0) = s & x(\tau) = s+\tau\\
\frac{du^h}{d\tau} = -u^h & u^h(0) = \phi(s) & -\ln u^h(\tau) = \phi(s)+\tau
\end{cases}
$$

or

$$
u^h(t,x) = e^{-t}\psi(x-t)
$$

regarding the particular we have that $u^p(t,x) = \frac 14e^{t+2x}$ verifies the particular equation then

$$
u(t,x) = e^{-t}\psi(x-t)+\frac 14e^{t+2x}
$$

and for $t=0$ we have

$$
\psi(x) + \frac 14e^{2x}=0
$$

then $\psi(x) = -\frac 14 e^{2x}$ and finally

$$
u(t,x) = \frac 14\left(-e^{-t}e^{2(x-t)}+e^{t+2x}\right)
$$

Answer (score 2):

Yes, by using the method of characteristics, one can find the explicit expression for the solution :
$$u(t,x)=\frac14\left(e^{t+2x}-e^{-3t+2x} \right)$$
The question is concise. The answer as well.